# Highcharts: Is it possible to compare series with external variable in tooltip formatter?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I'd like to compare a series with an external variable that has the same x axis but different y values. To make it easier to explain the problem a sample code is provided [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/3703/).

The data series are

```
series: [{data: [5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9]},
   {data: [4, 6, 7, 9, 5, 9, 12, 11, 9, 7, 6, 5]}]
```

and the external variable is

```
var extdata = [2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2];
```

They share the same x-axis (Jan, Feb, ... , Dec in this example). Suppose I want to display a tooltip "max" when the data point in a series for that month plus the corresponding entry in the external variable is at least 10 but retain the numerical value of the sum otherwise, so that the tooltip at March reads

```
March:
Series 1: 7
Series 2: 9
```

and that at April reads

```
April:
Series 1: 8
Series 2: Max
```

Is it possible to do this using only the tooltip formatter? How can this be achieved if it is not? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but the easiest I can think of is to format your extdata like this:

```
var extdata = {'Jan':2,
           'Feb':2,
           'Mar':2,
           'Apr':1,
           'May':0,
           'Jun':0,
           'July':0,
           'Aug':1,
           'Sep':1,
           'Oct':2,
           'Nov':2,
           'Dec':2};
```

Then in your tooltip function, you can reference it like this:

```
formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
        var month = this.x;
            $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                var total = point.y + extdata[month];
                s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' + (total>=10?'max':point.y);
            });
        return s;
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uhge/

By indexing the extdata on the month, you avoid having to work out which point you are hovering over. You can work this out if you want by iterating over the categories looking for the month name.

Comment: Thanks. I end up looking for the index though as my actual data have a lot more points and this is easier than changing the structure of the external variable. Is it possible to retrieve the index without finding a match using the x-axis variable? If this is possible I can simplify my code further and save a bit of computing power.

Answer (score 0):

For categorized, SteveP answer is pretty good one. But if you don't want to format data, use something like this:

```
s+= '<br/>Ext data: ' + extdata[this.points[0].point.x];
```

where `this.points[0].point.x` is equal to index of external data index. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/3707/)

However, if your xAxis is not categorized, you can simply get index by `this.x` as in previous answer [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/3709/)

Comment: Thanks - this works too. But my actual data is actually a 2-d array with the first dimension being the x-axis values, and hence `this.points[0].point.x` will return the x values rather than the integral index. I wonder if there's a way to find the index instead.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such property like 'index'. You can use `inArray()`  JS built-in function, where list of x-values you can find in: `this.points[0].series.xData`.